# How to filter traces by value in segments list in AWS X-Ray Traces

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-xray

In AWS CloudWatch -> X-Ray -> Traces I can find traces like:

```
{
    "Id": "1234",
    "Duration": 26.753,
    "LimitExceeded": false,
    "Segments": [
        {
            "Id": "1qaz",
            "Document": {
                "id": "1qaz",
                "name": "somesite.io",
                "start_time": 221,
                "trace_id": "1234",
                "end_time": 222,
                "parent_id": "qwerty",
                "inferred": true,
                "http": {
                    "request": {
                        "url": "https://somesite.io/api/SUPERID",
                        "method": "POST"
                    },
                    "response": {
                        "status": 200,
                        "content_length": 100
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    ]
  }
```

I wish to find trace with value `SUPERID` what is in above JSON in:
`Segments[?].Document.http.request.url`

To sum up: I'm looking for example query what should be entered to `Find` input to find above trace by `SUPERID` value

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Refer to [X-Ray filter expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-console-filters.html)
There are 2 ways:

1. filter by `http.url`
2. Add `SUPERID` in segment annotation, then filter it by `annotation.key`